# How to use form partial for custom create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, clone, partial

I have a trouble with creating custom create method. 
I'm using Projects model and projects controller. After new project is added it redirects to that projects show page. Here comes the problem. I have a button to call clone_project method since I need to create new project with the data from selected project and with empty name field. So, I've created route:

```
resources :projects do
  get 'clone/:id', action: 'clone_project', on: :collection
end
```

and a view page that uses form partial. With this I've manage just to edit existing project since I don't seem to get how to use form with post method like in create action.

Comment: in the new cloned form,do you need to show `OR` edit ??

Comment: The new form is to create record with data from existing. So it is create. But it works now, using dup method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Marija, is your question still open?

Comment: No. I've solved it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead render form partial with existing `project` you could try something like:

```
new_project = existing_roject.dup
new_project.title = ""
```

and then render form with this object